# remove empty fields in a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007, I have a listbox that is filtered by 4 comboboxes. Once the filter is set, some fields in the listbox are completely empty. Is there some way I can programmatically hide those fields? I know that it's possible to manually set field widths to 0, but that's not really viable in this case. Here is a snippet of the code; it is from the AfterUpdate event of one of the comboboxes. I'm not really sure what code is needed for anyone to help with this.

```
Me.OutTable.RowSource = "SELECT * " & _
"FROM FinalTable " & _
"WHERE [ID Maker.Axis] = '" & Me.Axis.Value & "' " & _
"AND [ID Maker.Test Type] = '" & TestType.Value & "' " & _
"AND [ID Maker.Billet Number] = " & BilletNumber.Value & " " & _
"AND [ID Maker.Billet Material] = '" & BilletMaterial.Value & "' "
```

Comment: How is the listbox populated?  how do user actions affect that?  Can you post some code?

Comment: @Smandoli For now, the listbox is populated by dumping all the data from another table into it. Inefficient, I know. For now, users will have no write privileges; they can only use the comboboxes and look at the contents of the listbox. I'll copy some code into the main post

Comment: Not necessarily inefficient.  Thanks for adding code.  I suggest you add code from a ComboBox event.

Comment: Is the problem a result of the data or the filtering applied to the data?  For starters, does `FinalTable` contain empty records?

Comment: Does `FinalTable` really contain a field named `ID Maker.Axis`?  If not, what is `ID Maker.Axis`?

Comment: @Smandoli FinalTable does contain empty records. It is essentially a mashup of many different data sources, which all contain data pertaining to similar items (ie ID Maker.Axis, Test Type, Billet Number, and Billet Material describe each entry). However, the rest of the fields are not necessarily identical, hence empty records

Comment: @HansUp FinalTable does contain a field named ID Maker.Axis

Comment: That surprises me.  Access 2007 refuses to let me include a period in a field name.

Comment: @HansUp I agree. And when I put a period in another file (like csv or Excel) and make it a linked table it get's turned into ` ID Maker#Axis` in Access

Comment: @HansUp Unless `FinalTable` is actually a query. You can have periods in column names in queries. You can see this if you join a table to itself and `Select *`. the output columns will all be prefaced with `Alias.column name`

Comment: @Brad Do you mean Access lets you include a period in a field expression alias?  I haven't found a way to do that, either.

Comment: @HansUp No I guess I take it back. That is what is output in gridview but you can't actually specify that in SQL. for example `SELECT  * FROM Table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN table1 as T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;` will show two columns as `T2.ID` and T1.ID`. But you can't say `Select T2.ID as [T2.ID]`. Maybe this is part of OPs confusion?

Comment: I suspect OP has, for example, two `Axis` columns in the construction of `FinalTable` and the column names get messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SELECT *` on a query that is not organized at the column level as you need it to be.

Try selecting for display only the 1-3 fields you are sure you'll want as columns in the listbox -- hopefully fields that always have a value.  (If you want more than 1-3 columns, try a small number just to get started.)

The right starting place may be re-organizing your "mash-up" query result.  Maybe you are using a UNION query, but it seems unlikely -- The UNION query has a funny way way of forcing you to think through your requirements.  You may want to try it.

I believe as you get coherent results on your query, the listbox may resolve itself.  To get more help with that, post information about your table structures and content.  It may deserve a separate post.